# Database to ListView - Filter out entries

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a SQLite database and I'm getting a ListView from the database through a SimpleCursorAdapter. This is the existing code:

```
Cursor c = mDatabase.query(
            "database",
            bla = new String[]{
                    "_id",
                    "title",
                    "message",
                    "time",
                    "date",
                    "done"
            },
            null, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.list_item, c,
                    new String[]{"title", "message", "time", "date"},
                    new int[]{R.id.txtv_title, R.id.txtv_message, R.id.txtv_time, R.id.txtv_date}
            );
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```

This works as intended and I'm getting my ListView.
Now I want that if the "done" field in my database contains the string "false" (instead of "true" ...), this row doesn't get into the ListView.

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a SQL then Android-related. What you're looking for is a Where-clause:

```
String query = "SELECT _id, title, message, time, date, done "+
"FROM database "+
"WHERE done = 'true' "+
"ORDER BY date";
```

To send this Query to your SQLite Database, you can use the rawQuery()-method:

```
final Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Comment: This is the solution, thank you! I didn't even think about doing it with the query...

Comment: But you can provide where and order by to query method without using rawQuery  ... Method query is esier to maintaince then rawQuery fx u can store static column array and table name so u can change that in one place not in every query string

Comment: I'm not a fan of the simple query()-method because I'm able to use SQL so why use something that does this stuff for me? Of cause, you can also use this methods, the result should be the same.

Comment: Yes results will be the same but fx u store all columns in static interface u use em in query, creating database and few other places and u find typo in column name ... With query and static column names u can find all occurenc easilly ... I'm not a fun query too ... I like to bulid contentprovider instead of messing with db in other places then in cp